# Update a value in the database through a text field without page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to update a value in the database through a text field without reloading the webpage. The problem is that when I return from the controller. I have tested with `Void` (gives me a a blank page after post) and with partialView but the rest of the layout does not appear after return.

Do I need to use partialview?

This is my code now.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ChangeHeaderName(Room room)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(room).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("_UpdateHeader", room);
    }
    return View(room);
}
```

Main view

```
<div>
@Html.Partial("_UpdateHeader")
</div>
```

PartialView

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeHeaderName", "Rooms",
                                        new AjaxOptions
                                        {
                                            UpdateTargetId = "targetDiv",
                                            OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
                                            OnFailure = "OnFailure"
                                        }, null, new { headerValue = "test" }))
{
    <h2>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "room-", @class = "button" } })</h2>
}

<script>
    function OnSuccess() {
        alert('Success');
    }
    function OnFailure(ajaxContext) {
        var response = ajaxContext.get_response();
        var statusCode = response.get_statusCode();
        alert('Failure');

        $('#targetDiv').empty();
    }

</script>
```

I don't get any alerts from the javascript!

How can I post to my controller without reloading the page? My save function works fine.

Comment: Have you included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No ;) I have now and it works. Thanks! Why no errors that something was missing?

Comment: Because without `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`, its just making a normal submit (there is no javascript involved). But the `Ajax` methods are now obsolete anyway (they have been dropped from MVC6) so I recommend you just use the jQuery `ajax()` methods instead - and you will get far more control.

Comment: Hence the "unobtrusive" bit in the script's filename. That's what unobtrusive means: it only *adds* functionality, but everything still works without it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Wow. Didn't know that they had finally removed those. Thank God.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax.BeginForm routing to new page instead of a partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460167/ajax-beginform-routing-to-new-page-instead-of-a-partial-view)